# How do I return firestore collection as json object?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a family tree component that works when I import the data from a json file.
I would like to use the data within my firestore collection 'family'
[image]

Below is my parent component where I am calling the data

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import FamilyTree from '../FamilyTree/FamilyTree';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { listenToFamilyFromFirestore } from '../../../app/firestore/firestoreService';
import { listenToFamily } from '../familyActions';
import useFirestoreCollection from '../../../app/hooks/useFirestoreCollection';

export default function FamilyDashboard() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { family } = useSelector((state) => state.family);

  useFirestoreCollection({
    query: () => listenToFamilyFromFirestore(),
    data: (family) => dispatch(listenToFamily(family)),
    deps: [dispatch],
  });

  return (
    <Grid>
      <Grid.Column width={16}>
        <FamilyTree family={family} />
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Here is my child component

```js
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import PinchZoomPan from 'pinch-zoom-pan';
import { IFamilyNode, IFamilyExtNode } from 'relatives-tree';
import ReactFamilyTree from 'react-family-tree';
import FamilyNode from '../../family/FamilyNode/FamilyNode';
import styles from '../FamilyTree/Family.module.css';
import nodes from '../../../app/api/family.json';
import { objectToArray } from '../../../app/common/util/util';

const myID = 'palmasandora';

const WIDTH = 70;
const HEIGHT = 110;

export default React.memo<{}>(function FamilyTree(family) {
  const [menuActive] = useState(false);
  const [rootId, setRootId] = useState<string>(myID);
  const modes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(family));
  //const onResetClick = useCallback(() => setRootId(myID), []);

  console.log('family', family);
  console.log('modes', modes);
  // console.log('test', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(family)));

  console.log('json nodes', nodes);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className={styles.root}>
        <PinchZoomPan
          //debug
          captureWheel
          min={0.3}
          max={2.5}
          className={`myCanvas ${styles.wrapper} ${
            menuActive ? `${styles.ADDED_CLASS}` : ''
          }`}
        >
          <ReactFamilyTree
            nodes={nodes as IFamilyNode[]}
            rootId={rootId}
            width={WIDTH}
            height={HEIGHT}
            canvasClassName={styles.tree}
            renderNode={(node: IFamilyExtNode) => (
              <FamilyNode
                key={node.id}
                node={node}
                isRoot={node.id === rootId}
                onSubClick={setRootId}
                style={{
                  top: '10px',
                  width: WIDTH,
                  height: HEIGHT,
                  transform: `translate(${node.left * (WIDTH / 2)}px, ${
                    node.top * (HEIGHT / 2)
                  }px)`,
                }}
              />
            )}
          />
        </PinchZoomPan>
        {/* {rootId !== myID && (
          <div className={styles.reset} onClick={onResetClick}>Reset</div>
          )} */}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
});
```

Below is a screen shot of my console log:
[image]

I would like to use the information within the first family array. It should look more like the json object being returned below.
I was able to store this correctly in my state, maybe I should use that? How would I go about that?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you using [Flatten data Structures](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#flatten_data_structures), you can codes similar to codes below.

[You can use the once() method to simplify this scenario: it triggers once and then does not trigger again.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once)

```html
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var username = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().username) || 'Anonymous';
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you but I am unsure how to apply this concept. Can you provide an example of how this would fit to what i am trying to do?